# What is the name for landing pages that are one long page?

Tags: landing-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There must be a science to single-page product sales sites. What is it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23825/there-must-be-a-science-to-single-page-product-sales-sites-what-is-it)

Really don't see them much anymore, but here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

**From comments:** These are "high pressure" sales pages, design to overload the user with information, sell them on the belief that what they're buying is what they need, normally have a lot of testimonials, highlighted text, etc. The pages I'm talking about are not user friendly, they're aggressive sales pitches designed to target users wanting to belief the webpage they just landed on will solve there problems for an "affordable" price. Here's an example: www_landingpagecashmachine_com (remove the underscores, since I'm attempting to avoid linking to a site like that...)

**Bonus points:** if you're able to tell me the name of the guy/company that popularized these types of pages; recall hearing about his company years ago, after he died in a crash while racing on a track with his Ferrari club on the west coast of the US. (**Update:** Appears [Corey Rudl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey_Rudl) was the guy's name, and his company was called "The Internet Marketing Center." Even with that info, I've still been unable to find the name for these type of pages.)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068407/jquery-one-page-scrolling-site-animated-deep-linking or more specifically http://www.maddim.com/demos/spark-r6/. I don't know of any specific man or company that died in a crash like that who popularized this technology, but it's not really anything specific. Rather, lots of people have made similar designs but I don't know who did it first.

Comment: @ionFish: Thanks, but neither of the examples you linked to are what I'm talking about. These are "high pressure" sales pages, design to overload try user with information, sell them on the belief that what they're buying is what they need, normally has a lot of testimonials, highlighted text, etc. -- Your links are more about the tech of a "user friendly" one page site. The pages I'm talking about are not user friendly, they're aggressive pitches designed to target users wanting to belief the webpage the just landed on will solve there problems for an "affordable" payment.

Comment: Here's an example: www_landingpagecashmachine_com (remove the underscores, since I'm attempting to avoid linking to a site like that... :-)

Comment: "bonus points"? Your question wording sounds like a quiz... do you already know the answer?

Comment: @w3d: Yes, I knew the answer at one point; meaning if the name given, I'd be able to confirm it doing a few Google searches. The guy made 100s of millions using these pages back in the late 90s.

Comment: "you don't see (these pages) much any more" - you're kidding, right?  The web is littered with them and if I end up on one it is 100% certainty I won't be buying anything there.  They just reek "scam" to me.

Comment: @Steve: Interesting, I had to search for 5-mins on Google to even find one example. How're you finding examples... :-)

Comment: @blunders - Oh, I couldn't tell by your small images. I know exactly what you're talking about. "Guides to make money" always. They're usually for an e-book to make you "thousands." I searched on the internet for five minutes, and I can't find anything about it. I think this is because Google removes this kind of result from searches? But I have received several by email over the last few years.

Comment: @ionFish: Yes, they're popular for digital goods such as eBooks, Softare, etc.  I've seen them called infomercial pages, but that's not what they're called. They're also not squeeze page, which are basically opt-in pages.

Comment: @ionFish: Updated the answer with the guys name (Corey Rudl) and a link to his wiki page; still unable to find the name of the pages though.

Comment: @Steve I come across these pages on very legitimate sites which are testing different layouts. 37 Signales used to use them and are lately testing very short pages. The squeeze pages you're running in to that are mostly scams are the clickbank type products. Though even some of those are decent at least the software that i've purchased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears the name of this type of landing page is simply "Sales letters", and that [Corey Rudl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey_Rudl) was the guy's name, and his company was called "The Internet Marketing Center."

Here's a review of the [The Internet Marketing Center landing page](http://www.mequoda.com/reviews-and-studies/landing-page-reviews/internet-marketing-center-landing-page-review/) when they still used this format; appears while the [company still is the one Corey Rudl started](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ainternetmarketing.com%20Corey%20Rudl), after reviewing the [current home page](http://www.internetmarketing.com/), it appears they no longer use this format.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it described as "Long sales letter" or "Long form sales letter".

There's a great series of posts on the [**37 Signals** site where they optimise the landing pages](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2977-behind-the-scenes-highrise-marketing-site-ab-testing-part-1) of [Highrise](http://highrisehq.com/) based on an [Anatomy of a Long Sales Letter at Visual Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/long-sales-letter-copywriting/).

Subsequent posts detail them [testing the changes](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2983-behind-the-scenes-ab-testing-part-2-how-we-test), and [why they finally went back to a shorter, simpler page](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2991-behind-the-scenes-ab-testing-part-3-final).

Essential reading for those designing landing and signup pages.